# How to use SIFT descriptor with in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have Python version 3.7.4 and OpenCV version 4.2.0.
I tried to iniciate SIFT detector as it described in [OpenCV 4.2.0 tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html), but a I always get the following errormessage:

**AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'**

```
import cv2

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

I found similar questions with previous OpenCV version but the answers didn't help for me.

Comment: It is in the non-free library, since it is copyright. You have to install with OpenCV. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d1/db4/group__xfeatures2d.html

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I found, that for using that I must install opencv-contrib-python. But it doesn't matter which version. :) The following worked for me:

pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/126)

Comment: Yes, opencv-contrib-python is where it is located.